# You do love me, don't you? I am?

Tags: riddle, word

You say I’m a breath of fresh air...

Then why do you spit on me?

Why do you break me down so loudly?

Why do you trap me in the darkest of places?

My skin may be pure white, but is my face not also red?

My cousin may be spicy hot but am I not sweet?

I am?

---

Edit: So, this is my first ever riddle and with all of these great answers, I think the riddle may not have been as specific as I thought it originally was. So, I'll try to add specificity.

Comment: Suggestion: if you think the riddle without hints lends itself to too many possible interpretations, maybe you should edit the hints into the riddle so that the question isn't "too broad". It should be uniquely solvable without hints, according to the [tag wiki](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/riddle/info). Hint 3 is easy to edit in, and probably hint 1 too. Don't take this as criticism; it looks like a great riddle! :-)

Comment: Thanks for your input (constructive criticism is good criticism). I removed the hints and baked them into the riddle. I'll continue editing if there continues to be more interpretations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it's

> Peppermint candy

You say I’m a breath of fresh air...

> Small peppermint candies are frequently given out as breath fresheners

Then why do you spit on me?

> They induce salivation in the mouth

Why do you break me down so loudly?

> They are very crunchy

Why do you trap me in the darkest of places?

> First the mouth, then the stomach

My skin may be pure white, but is my face not also red?

> They are white, but often decorated with red stripes

My cousin may be spicy hot but am I not sweet?

> Peppers are spicy but peppermint is a fresh, sweet flavor

Answer (score 6):

I think it is

> MINT GEL TOOTHPASTE

You say I’m a breath of fresh air...

> MINT

Then why do you spit on me?

> TO BRUSH THE TEETH

Why do you break me down?

> TO FORM BUBBLES

Why do you trap me in the darkest of places?

> CLEANING CAVITIES

My skin may be pure, but do I not bleed?

> TRANSPARENT GEL

My cousin may be hot but am I not sweet?

> COOL AND TASTIER. COUSIN MIGHT BE ALCOHOL MOUTHWASH

Alternatively it could be

> MINT ICE CREAM

Comment: This is also a good guess, but not quite. I added hints to my original question if you're interested.

Answer (score 5):

The last line made me think of the following solution, which I think I can make fit everything:

> CHILLI.

*You say I’m a breath of fresh air...*

> This could be a homophone reference, as fresh air is often **chilly**.

*Then why do you spit on me? 

Why do you break me down? 

Why do you trap me in the darkest of places?*

> All of this could refer to any kind of food: when you eat it, it gets covered in saliva, chewed into pieces, and buried in the pitch darkness of your stomach.

*My skin may be pure, but do I not bleed?*

> This is the line I'm least sure about...

*My cousin may be hot but am I not sweet?*

> Chilli can be very hot, but can also be used to make sweet chilli sauce.

Comment: Good guess, I especially like what you had in mind for the breath of fresh air. This is not what I had in mind, but I went ahead and added hints.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's a

> Chocolate covered cherry

You say I’m a breath of fresh air...

> People reward themselves with chocolate

Then why do you spit on me?
Why do you break me down?
Why do you trap me in the darkest of places?

> Eating it

My skin may be pure, but do I not bleed?

> pure chocolate, "bleeding" red cherry juice

My cousin may be hot but am I not sweet?

> I have no idea. I tried to think of a cousin to Red Hots, but I got nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Internet Explorer for sure.

I call it a breathe of fresh air whenever I (re)install windows, his cousin Chrome is hot (and IE thinks of himself as sweet).

And it is white skinned because it takes a long while to show webpages thus giving me a blank screen only after which it crashes (bleeds) and I bash at it loudly (break him down). And I keep IE in dark after I install chrome.

Edit: Tosen has now edited his post multiple times which might make this answer wrong.

Comment: Re-installing Windows doesn't make IE a breath of fresh air. Great user name by the way. :)

Comment: @Tosen Can you edit your question back?

Answer (score 1):

What about

> Just plain old chocolate

You say I’m a breath of fresh air...

> The delicious taste could "blow you away"

Then why do you spit on me? 
Why do you break me down? 
Why do you trap me in the darkest of places?

> Because we need to eat chocolate to satisfy our desiring love for chocolate

My skin may be pure, but do I not bleed?

> Chocolate is usually made of pure cocoa, the outside of the chocolate may melt

My cousin may be hot but am I not sweet?

> Hot chocolate is hot but regular chocolate is sweet.

Comment: This is good, but it's also not what I had in mind. I added hints if you're interested.